# how to extract file names with .txt from a text?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a text like below,

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur **sample1.txt** adipiscing elit. Morbi nec urna non ante varius semper eget vitae ipsum. Pellentesque habitant **sample2.txt** morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.

I have sample1.txt and sample2.txt in the above text. Name vary from sample1 and sample2. i just need to fetch the file name using c#.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged it LINQ:

```
var filesnames = text.Split(new char[] { }) // split on whitespace into words
                     .Where(word => word.EndsWith(".txt"));
```

Comment: I've always interpreted a tag of `linq` to mean linq is available, not linq is required; that's absurd.  As a programmer, the only real important thing is to solve the problem in an efficient and maintainable way.

Comment: @mellamokb: Well, it's a perfectly fine solution on both of those accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var filesnames = text.Split(' ')
                 .Where(o => o.EndsWith(".txt")).Select(o => o.SubString(o.LastIndexOf('.'))).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be possible with a regular expression if there's a good way to capture what your file names will look like.  I'm assuming here it's always `blah.txt` with alphanumeric characters:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.txt\b");
```